# Sign in with Facebook oauth, without full facebook.com access

Tags: facebook, ssl, oauth, proxy, facebook-oauth

A web application I'm currently developing needs users to be able to sign in via Facebook OAauth. However the problem is, all these users are behind a firewall that blocks access to facebook.com (company policy). We've looked into several solutions to get around this, like;

- Putting a (squid) proxy between Facebook and the users. This could solve the problem since squid supports fine grained regex-based ACLs. However, most of the Facebooks OAuth strategy runs on www.facebook.com and inspecting PATH_INFO to whitelist specific paths is not possible if the users use HTTPS (which is mandatory).
- Adding a proxy-like site in the DMZ of the firewall, which just passes and alters the urls/Facebook request. This obviously isn't the way to go either since it would basically mean users leave their credentials at our server, which is against Facebooks terms.
- Loosen up the firewall a bit to just enabling IP addresses needed for OAuth authentication, but as far as we could find out there isn't a dedicated IP or subdomain just for authentication (it would be nice if graph.facebook.com would provide something like this).

Any ideas for alternate solutions? Is this even possible at all?

Comment: "Any ideas for alternate solutions?"  If Facebook is an integral part of your app you're building, then your manager should be able to get the network guys to put in an exception to the firewall rules.  My company uses filter by role and by user.  So only those in a certain role get facebook as well as certain users who are overridden and get access anyhow.

Comment: Even if possible via a series of hacks, it will be prone to breaking things as Facebook is a fast moving company and development platform, and things change, sometimes surprisingly often.  It would be potentially be a fragile solution, and I can not imagine much more frustration than having a successful app with many users that all the sudden one day they can no longer use your site.

Comment: What about allowing the facebook.com/dialog/oauth URL in the firewall?

Comment: @DMCS I agree this would be the best solution. But I'm trying to figure out if there are any alternatives because this would be an absolute last resort.

Comment: @spotman Meh, yeah you're right. And besides that, it has some serious issues with the Facebook developer terms.

Comment: @chesles As far as I know that isn't possible. Facebook OAuth uses https, which afaik means that the firewall can only see the host the user is trying to connect to, and not the full path info (since that part is encrypted).

Comment: Actually what I wrote is your **first** resort, not last.

Answer (score 4):

No, because the OAuth [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) process for the API works by sending the user to a HTTPS URL on facebook.com you won't be able to easily distinguish between the traffic needed to setup the login to your app and other traffic to Facebook.com

You'll have the same problem trying to verify a Facebook user by use of a social plugin like the Like Button - you can't easily separate the traffic for the plugin and other traffic to facebook.com