# Filter controlled facebook login? for wifi

Tags: facebook, wifi, facebook-login

Im working on a wifi where you have to login with your facebook account in order to reach the internet or even the facebook inside.
I guess the problem is that facebook has a lot of login servers with different names.
As you can see on picture no. 1 I have already added those servers to my allowed outgoing connections but in many cases it just not enough. 
In addition the login box doesen't work properly as well. There is no css and pictures downloaded unfortunately. You can see this on picture no. 2.

Sorry for my english it's not my native tounge.

[Picture no. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qalKE.png)

[Picture no. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlsxs.png)

Any comments or advice really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sign in with Facebook oauth, without full facebook.com access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995467/sign-in-with-facebook-oauth-without-full-facebook-com-access)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with facebook is that they use their main domain to serve OAuth authentication dialog (quoting from [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/)):
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?...`

So using domain name based filtering (as attached pics suggest you do) is not really an option - opening access to oauth dialog opens access to whole facebook.

Funny enough exchange of authentication code to client token is done through:
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?...`

Compare this to google oauth:
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?...` serves auth dialog,
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` is used to get token